# What could happen if I use :without_protection=>true when creating a new model in rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I have encountered a problem in my application and realized that I could fix it by setting `:without_protection => true` when creating a model, e.g.:

```
Model.new(params[:model], :without_protection => true).
```

What exactly is rails protecting the models from? Thanks!

Comment: I know, but from what :)? What could the problem be, when I can solve it by not using protection?

Comment: What exactly was the problem you encountered that this fixed? There may be a better solution than using `:without_protection`

Comment: I have a view which involves three models, two of mich are created and one which is loaded form db. When I try to save this, I get the said problem.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's protection against unintended mass assignment.

The problem with the code you shown is that users can alter the form and change attributes you don't want them to change, like hashed passwords on users or a published status on posts.

You can use `attr_protected` and `attr_accessible` on models to protect attributes on your models to be overridden. When an attribute is protected than the value from `params` will be ignored (a notice will appear in your log).

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :one, :two
end
```

Before Rails 3.1, that was it. There was no way to configure it afterwards. Now, with Rails 3.1, you can assign roles:

```
class Model < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :one, :two, :as => :admin
  attr_accessible :one, :as => :regular_user
end
```

And specify it when doing mass updates (`new` or `update_attributes`):

```
Model.new(params[:model], :as => :regular_user)
```

Using `:without_protection`, will make every attribute free to be mass assigned and should be used VERY sparingly. Never use when you're passing in user data. You might use it in `db/seeds.rb` for example.

Comment: i just used it for seeds, for a write once flag (admin)

Answer (score 1):

This protects you against mass assignment.

Assume that, your model looks something like that:

```
class CreditCard
  belongs_to :user
end
```

You wouldn't like that someone will call your update action on creditcards_controller and pass another user_id attribute in params[:credit_card]

You can read more about mass assignment security [here](http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods.html)