# Unknown attribute "id" when importing csv to rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, psql

I'm importing a csv to my app and I'm getting a routing error "unknown attribute '﻿id' for TableName"

I understand so far that this should be due to my csv having columns that don't match with my table, but this isn't the case. I'm pretty sure it has to do with my column name in the .csv being "id", as that might be a reserved word, but I tried setting `id: false` in my `create_table` and I still got an error.

I'm still getting the hang of ruby so any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

schema:

```
class CreateContacts < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.2]
  def change
    create_table :contacts do |t|
      t.integer :id
      t.string :first_name
      t.string :last_name
      t.string :company
      t.string :email
      t.string :address1
      t.string :address2
      t.string :city
      t.string :state_long
      t.string :state
      t.string :phone

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

controller:

```
require 'csv'

class ContactController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  CSV.foreach('app/data/contact_data.csv', :headers => true) do |row|
    Contact.create!(row.to_hash)
  end
end
```

Comment: notice it says "unknown attribute 'id' for TableName", it does not say "unknown attribute 'id' for Contact". I'm not sure why you are importing the CSV inside a controller. It would be more appropriate as a rake task. Suggest you make a rake task (or even just try it in the rails console), and let us know what happens

Comment: Thanks. The error was actually for 'Contacts,' but I tried to make the question ambiguous and didn't succeed.  :p Regardless, I'll try that!

Comment: Note: Modern Ruby uses the `headers: true` notation instead of the old Ruby 1.8 `:headers => true` form. The new form is shorter, and also follows the same conventions used in other languages, like JavaScript.

Comment: Are you sure that you actually run your database migration successfully? Rails creates an `id` column automatically, I would expect it to raise an error when you try to add another `id` column manually. Please double-check the table structure in your database.

Comment: can you show the stacktrace? also beware: the `CSV.foreach` is also class-level on your controller; you should move it to a method or plug it in a model.

Answer (score 0):

id is attr_protected that is why you can not set it manually in create, you can set it like this

```
Contact.create!(row.to_hash, without_protection: true)
```

but be careful when setting without_protection to true. You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8175035/what-could-happen-if-i-use-without-protection-true-when-creating-a-new-model-i).

Comment: there does not appear to be any issue creating an ActiveRecord model while specifying the id. I confirmed in the Rails console that it's possible, b/c this was my first suspicion about the problem.

Comment: did you confirm that ```row.to_hash``` is producing correct hash?

Answer (score 0):

In Rails, `id` is generated automatically, so you don't need specify the id in the migration file. You can remove this line in migration file:

```
t.integer :id
```